# Extract Month from date as number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that accepts the date in the following format:

'31 AUG 2012'

I need the query to return the month as a number.  For the above date, the returned value would be 08

I have tried the following:

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '31 AUG 2012')
TO_DATE('31 AUG 2012', 'MM')
TO_CHAR('31 AUG 2012', 'MM')
```

All of which give me the below errors respectively:

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-01722: invalid number

How can this be accomplished?  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date '2012-08-31') FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM to_date('31 AUG 2012','DD MON YYYY'))
```

The date '' operator only accepts ISO format ...

```
date '2012-08-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you made mistake is you given only 'MM' as the format_mask instead you give 'DD/MM/YYYY', hope that would work as well

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM AB;
```

Output: **26/03/2013 15:15:34**

If you need only the month to be displayed try using this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) FROM AB;
```

the above will display the MAR as 3(considering today's date)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `08` to `8` because `08` is character field so i have used `to_number()` over `to_char` so that it will return exact number.

```
select to_number(to_char(to_date('31-AUG-2012','DD-MON-YYYY'),'MM')) from your_tbl;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select substr(to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy'),4,3) from dual;
```

Comment: Applying `to_date()` on `sysdate` is **totally** useless as `sysdate` is already a date. Even worse, this expression is subject to an implicit data type conversion based NLS settings and will throw an error on any enviroment where the default NLS date format is *not* `dd-mon-yyyy`. Did you maybe mean `to_char()` instead?